# Array returns 1 less row - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The method:

```
public function get_connections($member_id) {
            global $db;

            $sql = "SELECT `connection_id` FROM `my_connections` WHERE
                    `member_id` = '".$member_id."'";

            $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);    

            $list = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $connection_list[] = $list['connection_id'];

            }


            return $connection_list;            
        }
```

Where I call it: (Note: the above method is from the my_connections Class)

```
$mc = new my_connections;
$list = $mc->get_connections('206');
print_r($list);
```

The print_r displays 1 less row than in the DB, specifically the first row is getting omitted.

Comment: @MattClark Yes - if the member has only 1 connection, the it returns nothing, so im pretty sure its omitting the first record.

Comment: Consider switching to mysqli, as mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array($result); // <---
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Remove the first line there. You're fetching a row and doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the while loop is unnecessary. You can simply type

```
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT `connection_id` FROM `my_connections` WHERE
                `member_id` = '".$member_id."'";

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You will be sure that it only contains **connection_id**'s as that is all you are querying the DB for