# While loop doesn't outputs correct result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been working on this application which has a table named **funds** , this **funds** table maintains the incoming and outgoing of funds from user account.

Here's the database design :-

```
NAME          TYPE                       DEFAULT     NULL
recordid      int auto_increment                     NO
parentemail   varchar(255)                           NO
funds         int                                    NO
is_locked     varchar                    YES         NO
```

Ok, so suppose there are 4 entries in this table, two of them having as status **YES** and two of them having **NO** status, I'm using this query to get the sum and locked status from this table.

```
SELECT sum(funds) AS funds,is_locked AS status FROM funds where parentemail = '" . $email . "' GROUP BY is_locked
```

And then I'm using this code to put the value of locked funds (funds with status (is_locked) to YES) and unlocked funds (funds with status (is_locked) set to NO) to different variables;

```
$query3="SELECT sum(funds) AS funds,is_locked AS status FROM funds where parentemail = '" . $email . "' GROUP BY is_locked";
$result3=mysql_query($query3,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$ulfunds=0;
$lfunds=0;
while($row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
{
    if($row3['status'] == "NO") //if is_locked == NO, then funds are not locked and it would be stored in $ulfunds
    {
        $ulfunds=$ulfunds + $row3['funds'];
    }
    if($row3['status'] == "YES")//if is_locked == YES, then funds are are locked and would be stored in $lfunds
    {
        $lfunds=$lfunds + $row3['funds'];
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now if I echo `$lfunds(locked funds)` and `$ulfunds(unlocked funds)`, I get correct value for $lfunds (locked funds, is_locked == YES) but I get output `0` (the default value) for the `$unfunds` (unlocked funds).

How can I fix this so that I should get the correct value in both the variables?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add the row values to the variables. There's only one row for each status, you can just do an ordinary assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array returns 1 less row - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054903/array-returns-1-less-row-php)

Comment: I recommend you check out Laravel.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins
I once gave a thought to shift to a framework. But I guess I need to have good practice of OOP right?

Comment: @Ankur If I were to start in PHP all over again I'd just start the right way from the beginning.  I went down the path you're on right now and it would have been nice just to have skipped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your code,

```
 $row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either 
Mysql_fetch_array()

Or

Mysql_fetch_assoc()

But not both. Try putting the loop on mysql_fetch_array() it should work